# rotate ccobject with kmglrotatef

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am trying to rotate a     `CCObject` using `kmglrotatef` in `cocos 2d x`. 
  I am using the following line of code in my own object class which is inherited from 
      `CCObject`.

```
   kmGLRotatef(20.0f, _xPos, _yPos, 1);
```

Here  `(_xPos,_yPos)` - centre of the     `CCObject`. The problem is the entire screen is rotating. I want to rotate the object only. Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you use `object->setRotation();`

Comment: setRotation rotate the object . I want rotation with respect to X :)

Comment: after trying for 2 - 3 days I am now able to rotate the object. But I want rotation with respect to x axis. Anybody please help. :)